# GraphQL Error field type must be Input Type but got:

Tags: javascript, graphql

Here is the mutation:

```
const createNotebook = mutationWithClientMutationId ({
    name: 'CreateNotebook',
    inputFields: {
        token: {
            type: GraphQLString,
        },

        details: {
            type: NotebookDetails,
        },
    },
    outputFields: {

    },
    async mutateCRNotebook(input, context) {
        const data = getJSONFromRelativeURL(input.token);

    },
});
```

Here is the schema used in the details field of the mutation:

```
const NotebookDetails = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'NotebookDetails',
    interfaces: [nodeInterface],

    fields: () => ({
        id: globalIdField('NotebookDetails'),

        description: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            description: '...',
            resolve(obj) {
                return obj.description;
            },
        },

        language: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            description: '...',
            resolve(obj) {
                return obj.language;
            },
        },

    }),

});
```

Error I am getting on running this code is :

```
api_1    | Error: CreateNotebookInput.details field type must be Input Type but got: NotebookDetails.
api_1    |     at invariant (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:19:11)
api_1    |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:698:58
api_1    |     at Array.forEach (native)
api_1    |     at GraphQLInputObjectType._defineFieldMap (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:693:16)
api_1    |     at GraphQLInputObjectType.getFields (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:682:49)
api_1    |     at typeMapReducer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:224:26)
api_1    |     at typeMapReducer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:190:12)
api_1    |     at Array.reduce (native)
api_1    |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:217:36
api_1    |     at Array.forEach (native)
api_1    |     at typeMapReducer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:210:27)
api_1    |     at Array.reduce (native)
api_1    |     at new GraphQLSchema (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:98:34)
api_1    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/schema/index.js:39:16)
api_1    |     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
api_1    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
```

I have used this syntax with queries and they worked correctly. But, they are returning error with a mutation.
What is incorrect in my code and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In GraphQL, an `input` cannot be used as a `type` and a `type` cannot be used as an `input`. Unfortunately, even if the fields appear identical to an existing type, you always have to define a separate input to use as an argument. Try something like this:

```
const NotebookDetailsInput = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'NotebookDetailsInput',
  fields: () => ({
    id:          { type: GraphQLID },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    language:    { type: GraphQLString }, 
  })
});
```

If using SDL, the same type would look like this:

```
input {
  id: ID
  description: String
  language: String
}
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881719/6024220) for an extensive explanation of *why* it's necessary to do this.

Comment: This took me way too long to catch on to but seems quite "obvious" once you catch on!

Comment: your answer should be flashing on top of their website

Answer (score 41):

**For those who are using `graphql-tools` and stumble accross this post, documentation is [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) at GraphQL's Website.**

**My Example using graphQL tools** is here **below**: (this has an input inside of an input AKA an `ImageInput` inside the `SocialPostInput`)

//mutation file

```
extend type Mutation {
    SchedulePost ( 
        socialPost: SocialPostInput,
        schedule: ScheduleInput
     ): ScheduledPost
}`
```

//Schedule and SocialPost file

```
type Image {
    id: String
    url: String
}
type SocialPost {
    id: String
    GCID: String
    message: String
    image: Image
}
input ImageInput {
    url: String
}
input SocialPostInput {
    GCID: String
    message: String
    image: ImageInput
}
type Schedule {
    id: String
    month: Int
    date: Int
    hour: Int
    minute: Int
}
input ScheduleInput {
    id: String
    month: Int
    date: Int
    hour: Int
    minute: Int
}`
```

Answer (score 22):

If you describe schema within schema.graphql file, just replace type to input:

Wrong:

```
type SomeData {
  someField: String!
}
```

Right:

```
input SomeData {
  someField: String!
}
```

Comment: I follow your answer @zemil, and it works for me. Thank you. My question is: I have a large schema language, and i have to clone the type to make it an input. Is there existing options that will minimize the redundancy of it because their only difference is the type/input code, the fields are all the same.

Comment: @JurP check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452982/reusing-input-type-as-fragment-in-graphql

Answer (score 3):

Please change `type CreateNotebookInput` to `input CreateNotebookInput`

Comment: And what would that do?

Comment: Because this bug showing need the input, not a type. Changing will fix this bug

Answer (score 0):

Here is the schema used in the details field of the mutation

```
const NotebookDetails = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'NotebookDetails',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        description: { type: GraphQLString },
        language: { type: GraphQLString },

    }),

});
```