# Graphql use Input type to search data

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I have problem searching with using `Input data` in `graphql`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/dictionary/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class DictionaryController {
    @Value("classpath:items.graphqls")
    private Resource schemaResource;
    private GraphQL graphQL;
    private final DictionaryService dictionaryService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadSchema() throws IOException {
        File schemaFile = schemaResource.getFile();
        TypeDefinitionRegistry registry = new SchemaParser().parse(schemaFile);
        RuntimeWiring wiring = buildWiring();
        GraphQLSchema schema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(registry, wiring);
        graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();
    }

private RuntimeWiring buildWiring() {

            DataFetcher<String> fetcher9 = dataFetchingEnvironment ->
            getByInput((dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("example")));

        return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type("Query", typeWriting ->
                   typeWriting
                    .dataFetcher("getByInput", fetcher9)
                    )
                .build();
    }


public String getByInput(Character character) {
    return "testCharacter";
}
  }
```

`items.graphqls` file content:

```
type Query {
   getByInput(example: Character): String
}

input Character {
    name: String
}
```

When asking for resource like that:

```
query {
    getByInput (example: {name: "aa"} )
}
```

Character DTO:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Character {
    protected String name;
}
```

I've got an error:

```
"Exception while fetching data (/getByInput) : java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to pl.graphql.Character",
```

How should the query look like?

**Edit**

If i change to:

```
public String getByInput(Object character)
```

The codes runs fine - but i want convert to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the input argument which the type is the `input` type , `graphql-java` will convert it to a `Map`.

In your case the query is  `getByInput (example: {name: "aa"} )` which the `example` argument is the `input` type . So ,

```
dataFetchingEnvironment.get("example");
```

will return a Map with the structure (key="name" , value="aa") .Then you try to cast the map to `Character` which definitely gives you an error since they are totally different types.

To convert a Map to a `Character` , `graphql-java` will not help you for such conversion. You have to implement the conversion codes by yourselves or use other libraries such as [Jackson , Gson , Dozer or whatever libraries you like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)  for converting a map to your domain object (i.e. Character).

Comment: Then what for are `input` types in `grapql` good for? Maybe i don't understand it correctly. But dealing with custom transaltion from `object` / `map` is to much work in my opinion. Usually do you use it in some other way ? I reallt can not understand - why i am making `Character` type and `grapql` won't search for this `class` in my code to make it match and cast etc. It's kinda working silly right now.

Comment: here is why  input type good for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743253/whats-the-point-of-input-type-in-graphql . If you think it is too much work to do for translating a map to your domain object , that 's why you need to a library to help you. I personally use Jackson for such conversion.

Comment: Yes . that 's why someone come up the another framework on top of `graphql-java` such as this https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr to reduce the boilerplate codes that you are concerned with, but I personally did not tried it yet.

Comment: github issue that talks about this
https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/777