# Read argument on field passed via variable in GraphQL Java

Tags: graphql-java

I have a GraphQL operation which returns a type containing a field. This field takes an argument I'd like to read in the data fetcher.

If the argument is hard-coded (as `myArg1` is below), I can directly read its value. If the argument is passed via a variable (as `myArg2` is below), I can only read the variable's name, and not its value.

I could manually check each argument's type (e.g., `VariableReference`, `StringValue`), and accordingly find the variable's value on the `DataFetchingEnvironment`, but this is cumbersome. Since GraphQL Java has this info, is it possible for me to directly read the argument's value?

Here's a demo:

```kotlin
val registry = SchemaParser().parse(
    """
    type Query {
        myOperation: MyType!
    }

    type MyType {
        myField(myArg1: String!, myArg2: String!): Boolean!
    }
    """
)
val wiring = newRuntimeWiring()
    .type("Query") { builder ->
        builder.dataFetcher("myOperation") { env ->
            val myField = env.mergedField.singleField.selectionSet.selections[0] as Field
            val args = myField.arguments.map { it.value }
            println(args[0])
            println(args[1])
            true
        }
    }
    .build()
val schema = SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(registry, wiring)
val graphQl = newGraphQL(schema).build()
val query = """
    query MyOperation(${"$"}myArg2: String!) { 
        myOperation { 
            myField(myArg1: "myVar1", myArg2: ${"$"}myArg2) 
        } 
    }
"""
val builder = ExecutionInput.Builder().query(query).variables(mapOf("myArg2" to "myVar2"))
graphQl.execute(builder) // Trigger data fetcher.
```

Output:

```
StringValue{value='myVar1'}
VariableReference{name='myArg2'}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's no way to do this. GraphQL Java doesn't do it because it claims that it doesn't have enough information to give the variable's value when the data fetcher is invoked. This is false because the data fetcher has both the variable's name, and its value. They probably don't want to implement this because they expect you to use DTOs instead. GraphQL Java provides DTOs with the required information.

Create a DTO:

```kotlin
class MyTypeDto {
    fun getMyField(env: DataFetchingEnvironment): Boolean {
        env.arguments // has the values for both arguments
        return false
    }
}
```

and a data fetcher:

```kotlin
dataFetcher("myOperation") { env -> MyTypeDto() }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to be so complicated. If you are inside 'myField' 's data fetcher , you can simply get the value of the argument using `env.getArgument()` :

```java
String myArgumentValue = env.getArgument("myArgument");
```

For the input type argument, it will return a Map. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270992/339637)). For the scalar argument , what java object type will be returned depends on the `Coercing` of the underlying Scalar implementation.

Comment: The issue is that I'm unable to read the argument's value. I have updated my question to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get there with something like the following.  You'll need to trim ! modifiers from the type names.

One thing I haven't figured out with this method of traversing the schema within a DataFetcher is sometimes the field definition arguments resolve to GraphQLInputObjectTypes in which case you need to cast them and call getName().

```java
environment.getFieldDefinition().getArguments().forEach((arg) -> {
        System.out.println("Env field def arg: " + arg.getName() + ", type: " + arg.getType().toString());
});
```