# GraphQL array/list variables?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I want to use an array/list as variable for a GraphQL mutation like this:

Schema

```
type User {
  id: Id!
  email: String
  name: String
  bookmarks: [Bookmark]
}

type Mutation {
  updateUser(data: UserInput!): User
}

input UserInput {
  email: String
  name: String
  bookmarks: [Bookmark]
}

type Bookmark {
  vidId: String!
  timestamp: Int!
}
```

Mutation

```
mutation($email: String, $name: String, $bookmarks: [{vidId: String!, timestamp: Int!}]) {
  updateUser(data: {email: $email, name: $name, bookmarks: $bookmarks}) {
    email
    name
  }
}
```

However, the variable syntax in the mutation regarding the bookmarks array seems invalid. How can I pass in an array as a GraphQL variable?

Comment: Should that be `input Bookmark` instead of `type Bookmark`?

Comment: I'm not sure, `Bookmark` is also used elsewhere outside the input type. Does everything in the input type have to be recursively input types? Edit: I added another type to show this

Comment: Yes, [I'm pretty certain that they do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41743253/1048572). Does your schema validate?

Comment: Thanks, I got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL does not support anonymous type declarations (that `{vidId: String!, timestamp: Int!}` literal), you must refer to a named type (or a list of it or a non-null of it). So just write

```graphql
mutation($email: String, $name: String, $bookmarks: [BookmarkInput]) {
#                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  updateUser(data: {email: $email, name: $name, bookmarks: $bookmarks}) {
    email
    name
  }
}
```

instead with a

```graphql
input BookmarkInput {
  vidId: String!
  timestamp: Int!
}
```

defined in your schema.

Comment: I see. Does this have to be an input type? I thought only the outmost layer has to be input type, because String, Int are not input types

Comment: @rasperry `String` and `Int` are scalar types (not object types). Those can be contained in both input and output types.